# Object can be seen through face texture

Tags: texturing

I can't find any solution. [image]I have created a scene from some of my assets of a room where wall's upper part is made by single face. I've snapped them together (inside part and outside part) but their texture is glitching through each other. I've could sovle that by deleting one part of them but that would make another issue after exporting the scene whould be from one side transparet. Also noticed when I've snapped some object to the inside face part the object is glitching even through the outside part (seen on picture).

Is there any way how to solve it without deleting faces?

Thanks for any response.

Comment: [Z-fighting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Z-fighting) - make sure the surfaces don't overlap - move the shields slightly away from the wall.

Comment: That funky pattern is called "Z-fighting" - it's what happens when 2 faces are in the exact same spot and blender can't tell which one to put "in front". Move the object(s) slightly forward (even .0001 will do).

Comment: It helped quite well. Thanks.